# Why can't I add to the middle of an array with Perl's Tie::File?

Tags: perl, file

File :

```
#comment1
#comment2
#comment3
#START HERE

a:  a@email.com
b:  b@email.com
```

my perl program :

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Tie::File;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', 'ala.txt' or die $!;

my $rec = 'p:                                        p@email.com';

my $flag =1 ;
my $add_flag = 0;
for my $i (0..$#array) {
        next if ($array[$i] =~ /^\s*$/);
        if ( $flag == 1 )  {
                if ($array[$i] =~ /#START HERE/ ) {
                  $flag = 0;
                }
                else {
                  next ;
                }
        }
    if (($array[$i] cmp $rec) == 1) {
           splice @array, $i, 0, $rec;
          $add_flag = 1;
        last ;
    }
}

if ( $add_flag == 0 ) {
   my $index = $#array+1;
   $array[$index] = $rec ;

}
```

the recording adding end of file always . I am trying to add to middle or begin or end like aplphbetical order

**Edit 2 :**

I want to do with Tie::FILE only .

after add :

(after 2 execution )

```
#comment1
#comment2
#comment3
#START HERE

a:  a@email.com
b:  b@email.com
p:                                        p@email.com
a:                                        ab@email.com # if i add another record of a
```

Expection :

```
#comment1
#comment2
#comment3
#START HERE

a:  a@email.com
a:  ab@email.com
b:  b@email.com
p:                                        p@email.com
q:                                        q@email.com
```

Comment: Please show example output, desired and actual.

Comment: Hints: always use `use strict; use warnings;`.  And use Data::Dumper to check that you are modifying data structures in the way you think you are.

Comment: @Ether - his code (as is) passes both strict and warnings... though that is a absolutely correct advice to always follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem has nothing to do with tie, but with `splice`**.

Your problem is with how you use `splice`:

- You need to have LENGTH of 0, not 1

  because now you're **removing 1 array element at index `$i` before adding your record**.

  In your case, most likely, all your tests were meant to add something as second last, so you removed the last element and as such, your element went to the end.

Try:

`splice @array, $i, 0, $rec;`

---

Here's my test:

```
$ cat ala.txt
#comment1
#comment2
#comment3
#START HERE

a:  a@email.com
b:  b@email.com

$ grep 'my $rec' junk/s2.pl
my $rec = 'p:                                        p@email.com';

$ perl5.8 junk/s2.pl

$ cat ala.txt
#comment1
#comment2
#comment3
#START HERE

a:  a@email.com
b:  b@email.com
p:                                        p@email.com

$ grep 'my $rec' junk/s2.pl
my $rec = 'a:          ab@email.com # if i add another record of a';

$ perl5.8 junk/s2.pl

$ cat ala.txt
#comment1
#comment2
#comment3
#START HERE

a:          ab@email.com # if i add another record of a
a:  a@email.com
b:  b@email.com
p:                                        p@email.com
```

---

**OLDER TEST**

I copied your entire code, added `my $length = $ARGV[0] || 0;` at the beginning and changed `splice` line to `splice @array, $i, $length, $rec;`

```
# Offset 1
$ cp ala_orig.txt ala.txt ; echo "BEFORE: #############" ; cat ala.txt ; 
  perl5.8 junk/s2.pl 1 ; echo "AFTER #############" ; cat ala.txt 
BEFORE: #############
#aaa
#START HERE
b: x
c:y
u:a
z:y
AFTER #############
#aaa
#START HERE
b: x
c:y
p:                                        p@email.com
z:y

# Offset 0
$ cp ala_orig.txt ala.txt ; echo "BEFORE: #############" ; cat ala.txt ; 
  perl5.8 junk/s2.pl 0 ; echo "AFTER #############" ; cat ala.txt 
BEFORE: #############
#aaa
#START HERE
b: x
c:y
u:a
z:y
AFTER #############
#aaa
#START HERE
b: x
c:y
p:                                        p@email.com
u:a
z:y
```

Comment: Please post ACTUAL error case that doesn't work (e.g. starting array and the record to add that's added to the end instead of middle, AFTER you fix splice to have 0 lengh. See my updated sample

Comment: i am looking for with tie file ... because i want to write into file

Comment: @SCNCN2010 - In order to help you further, you need to copy and paste: An exact program you used (with `splice` fixed as per my answer), your file's starting content, and the file's content after running the program, showing that the order was not preserved. Thanks

Comment: @SCNCN2010 - When I try to add your second "a:" record it gets before the first one, not at the end.